# How to access Webservices(eventful.com) from Phonegap

Tags: soap, cordova, xml-parsing

How to Access Particular website like (eventful.com) API in Phonegap using Xml Parsing, For eg I will press search button by texting like "Banglore"  in my phonegap means it retrieve events in banglore from eventful website.please give a simple and clear demo using some sample websites. Thanks in advance

Comment: will they provide you their private API?

Comment: ya they provide API key after registration My Api Key is SC4Hq4STTW3gD79X  from eventful.com